# SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose is not closing

Tags: jsom

I had written the below code to get the information of SharePoint list , And also I had used SP.UI.ModalDialog .
Unfortunately the dialog box is not getting closed.

Can any one please help me what's wrong in my below code

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
alert('start script');
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myfunction1, "sp.js");

function myfunction1() {
        var dialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Processing...', 'Request is in progress...', 80, 300);
        retrieveListItems().done(function (data) {
            dialog.close(0);
            dialog = null;
            //processing your data
            alert("Data Loaded");
        });
    }

function retrieveListItems()
{
alert('enters function');

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('orderetails');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='TRUE' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>");

this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(collListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync( Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed) );

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args)
{
   var listItemInfo = '';
   var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                //alert('title ' + oListItem.get_item('Title'));

              listItemInfo +=' <strong>Table top Sessions:</strong> ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') +' <br />';

              //  alert("Lookup Value is" + +columnFieldValue);
                }
$('#divHelloWorld').html(listItemInfo );
}


function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
{
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +'\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
<p id="divHelloWorld">Hello World!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the SP.UI.DialogResult directly, instead of using the index.  So, dialog.close(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try closing from the DOM parent window directly.

```
window.parent.waitDialog.close();
```